# WiX Uninstall functionality with StandardBootstrapperApplication

Tags: wix, uninstallation, burn, wix3.7

I've built a very basic installer for a bundle of applications with dependencies and that handles a restart for a .NET package.  What I'm running into now, however, is the problem where the uninstall action only uninstalls the installer itself, which shows up in the program list.  All of the other .exe files that run installation processes remain installed.  Is there any simple way to handle this installation? I'm still very new to the WiX toolset and didn't want to dive really deep into a custom installer.  Here is my bundle:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"
  xmlns:netfx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/NetFxExtension"
     xmlns:bal="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/BalExtension" 
     xmlns:util="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/UtilExtension">
  <Bundle Name="Visible EP Installer" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="VEP" UpgradeCode="8d1a4e2a-be3f-4b51-824b-75652ae98bad">
    <BootstrapperApplicationRef Id="WixStandardBootstrapperApplication.RtfLicense" >
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication
          LicenseFile="..\VisibleEP EULA-ver2.rtf"
          LogoFile="..\VEPLogo_HeartOnlyBlack(50x50).png"
        />
    </BootstrapperApplicationRef>
    <?define NetFx45MinRelease = 378389?>
    <util:RegistrySearch
        Id="NETFRAMEWORK45"
        Variable="NETFRAMEWORK45"
        Root="HKLM"
        Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
        Value="Release"
        Result="value" />
    <Chain>
      <ExePackage Id="NetFx45Redist" Cache="no" Compressed="yes" PerMachine="yes" Permanent="yes" Vital="yes" InstallCommand="/q /norestart" RepairCommand="/q"
              SourceFile="..\VEP Deploy\Setup Files\dotNetFx45_Full_setup.exe"
              DetectCondition="NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx45MinRelease)"
              InstallCondition="(NOT NETFRAMEWORK45 &gt;= $(var.NetFx45MinRelease))">
        <ExitCode Value="1641" Behavior="forceReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="3010" Behavior="forceReboot"/>
        <ExitCode Value="0" Behavior="success"/>
        <ExitCode Behavior="error"/>
      </ExePackage>
      <ExePackage
        SourceFile="..\VEP Deploy\Setup Files\Encoder_en.exe"
        Permanent="no"
        InstallCommand="/q"
        RepairCommand="/q">
        <ExitCode Behavior="success"/>
      </ExePackage>
      <ExePackage
        SourceFile="..\VEP Deploy\Setup Files\vcredist_x86.exe"
        Permanent="no"
        InstallCommand="/q"
        RepairCommand="/q">
        <ExitCode Behavior="success"/>
      </ExePackage>
      <ExePackage
        SourceFile="..\VEP Deploy\Setup Files\vcredist_x64.exe"
        Permanent="no"
        InstallCommand="/q"
        RepairCommand="/q">
        <ExitCode Behavior="success"/>
      </ExePackage>
      <ExePackage
        SourceFile="..\VEP Deploy\Setup Files\vep_setup.exe"
        Permanent="no">
        <ExitCode Behavior="success"/>
      </ExePackage>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

I know that handling the exit codes for the last few is a bit hackish but I'm not all that concerned with that at the moment so long as it isn't impacting my other problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to supply `UninstallCommand` attribute values so Burn knows how to uninstall the .exes.

Comment: Ok what sort of command line arguments can be passes to the uninstallcommand? I just tried it and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: Any string. An .exe package can be anything so Burn can't assume there's a standard switch for each operation. Try "/uninstall" to start.

Comment: It works thanks! Any idea how to stop the bootstrapper from installing itself?

Comment: Sorry, don't know what you mean?

Comment: When I look at control panel to uninstall from a list of programs the installer itself is in that list...I've been told it is undesirable and have been working on a way to have it not in that list but can't seem to figure out a way to do that.  I don't think its exactly possible.

Comment: It's not. The bundle must be registered so the user can run uninstall on the bundle itself.